# Pyspark - How to calculate file hashes

Tags: pyspark

I have a bunch of `CSV` files in a mounted blob container and I need to calculate the 'SHA1' hash values for every file to store as inventory. I'm very new to `Azure cloud` and `pyspark` so I'm not sure how this can be achieved efficiently. I have written the following code in `Python Pandas` and I'm trying to use this in `pyspark`. It seems to work however it takes quite a while to run as there are thousands of CSV files. I understand that things work differently in `pyspark`, so can someone please guide if my approach is correct, or if there is a better piece of code I can use to accomplish this task?

```
import os
import subprocess
import hashlib
import pandas as pd

class File:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

        
     def get_hash(self):
        hash = hashlib.sha1()
        with open(self.path, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash.update(chunk)
        self.md5hash = hash.hexdigest()
        return self.md5hash

path = '/dbfs/mnt/data/My_Folder' #Path to CSV files
cnt = 0
rlist = []


for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for fi in files:
        if cnt < 10: #check on only 10 files for now as it takes ages!
            f = File(os.path.join(path, fi))
            cnt +=1
            hash_value = f.get_hash()
            results = {'File_Name': fi, 'File_Path': f.filename, 'SHA1_Hash_Value': hash_value}
            rlist.append(results)

            print(fi)
df = pd.DataFrame(rlist)
     
print(str(cnt) + ' files processed')

df = pd.DataFrame(rlist)
#df.to_csv('/dbfs/mnt/workspace/Inventory/File_Hashes.csv', mode='a', header=False) #not sure how to write files in pyspark!
display(df)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to treat the files as blobs and not read them into a table. I would recommend using `spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles` this would land you an `RDD` of pairs where the key is the file name and the value is a file-like object, on which you can calculate the hash in a map function (`rdd.mapValues(calculate_hash_of_file_like)`)

For more information, refer to the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.binaryFiles.html#pyspark.SparkContext.binaryFiles

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try this out :)

Comment: I tried this but I get an error `name 'calculate_hash_of_file_like' is not defined`. Probably a dumb question, but is this `calculate_hash_of_file_like` not an in-built function?

Comment: No it is not, you have to implement it

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error that I don't understand. I've updated the code per your suggestion and posted the error here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/70800984/6900402