# Pyspark - Code to calculate file hash/checksum not working

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have the below `pyspark` code to calculate the SHA1 hash of each file in a folder. I'm using `spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles` to get an RDD of pairs where the key is the file name and the value is a file-like object, on which I'm calculating the hash in a map function `rdd.mapValues(map_hash_file)`. However, I'm getting the below error at the second-last line, which I don't understand - how can this be fixed please? Thanks

Error:
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 66.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 66.0`

Code:

```
#Function to calulcate hash-value/checksum of a file
def map_hash_file(row):
    file_name = row[0]
    file_contents = row[1]
    sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    sha1_hash.update(file_contents.encode('utf-8'))
    return file_name, sha1_hash.hexdigest()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles('/mnt/workspace/Test_Folder', minPartitions=None)

#As a check, print the list of files collected in the RDD
dataColl=rdd.collect()
for row in dataColl:
    print(row[0])

#Apply the function to calcuate hash of each file and store the results
hash_values = rdd.mapValues(map_hash_file)

#Store each file name and it's hash value in a dataframe to later export as a CSV
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=hash_values)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get your expected result if you do the following:

- Change `file_contents.encode('utf-8')` to `file_contents`. `file_contents` is already a of type `bytes`
- Change `rdd.mapValues(map_hash_file)` to `rdd.map(map_hash_file)`. The function `map_hash_file` expects a tuple.

Also consider:

- Adding an `import hashlib`
- Not collecting the content of all files to the driver - you risk consuming all the memory at the driver.

With the above changes, your code should look something like this:

```
import hashlib
#Function to calulcate hash-value/checksum of a file
def map_hash_file(row):
    file_name = row[0]
    file_contents = row[1]
    sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    sha1_hash.update(file_contents)
    return file_name, sha1_hash.hexdigest()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles('/mnt/workspace/Test_Folder', minPartitions=None)

#Apply the function to calcuate hash of each file and store the results
hash_values = rdd.map(map_hash_file)

#Store each file name and it's hash value in a dataframe to later export as a CSV
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=hash_values)
display(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the updates as you suggested and ran the code on a folder containing 700 `csv` files but got the following error - `The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.` When run on a much smaller folder containing only 10 very small `csv` files, it runs fine. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I actually tried running the updated code after removing `dataColl=rdd.collect()
for row in dataColl:
    print(row[0])`. And I started getting the original error again at the second-last line (`createDataFrame`). Could it be because the code is trying to read all 700 files in the memory and therefore crashing? If so, can this be avoided?

Comment: For your first questions: when doing a collect with large files, you are likely to consume all the memory on the driver since you are moving the content of all files to the driver. I don't have any good clue for your second question, but I have updated my answer with a snippet of the code that I am running with. That works for me.

Comment: Thank you. I have the exact same code as your updated answer but I get the error- Maybe because I’m reading 700GB of files. It’s a shame that databricks can’t distribute the load amongst the available nodes rather than reading all files into the memory of the driver.

Comment: Just tested this out on ~10000 files totaling ~700GB on Azure Databricks. That is working fine.

Comment: Strange! Let me try running it on a different cluster -maybe that would fix the issue on my side.